# The outer box does not fit the input field

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a login form. The outer box of the form is big and does not fit with the input field. How can I minimize the size of the outer box? I am trying it for the first time. So, I have no idea.

templatemo_style.css: The css part

```
form {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
}

/* Full-width inputs */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-content: center;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 3px 22px 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;

}

/* Add a hover effect for buttons */
button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra style for the cancel button (red) */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the avatar image inside this container */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

/* Avatar image */
img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
}

/* The "Forgot password" text */
span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

index.jsp: Html code for the form

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Student Profile</title>
    <link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>

<form action="index.jsp">


    <div class="container">
        Username:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

        Password:
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
        <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is 
Change the **Html** Like this

```
     <div class="container">

  <form action="index.jsp">Username:
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

        Password:
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>


    <div  style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
        <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

And your css Like this

```
form {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;padding: 10px;
}

/* Full-width inputs */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-content: center;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 3px 22px 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;

}

/* Add a hover effect for buttons */
button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Extra style for the cancel button (red) */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the avatar image inside this container */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

/* Avatar image */
img.avatar {
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
    margin: 25px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
}
enter code here

/* The "Forgot password" text */
span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

the result will be[image]

hope this will do

Comment: How do I align my form to the center of the page. Can you help

Comment: This will do ,  i think....
form {
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
margin-top:25%;

}

Comment: Didn't work:
form {
 border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
 padding: 14px 10px;
 width: 40%;
 height: 30%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;

}

Answer (score 0):

If you put your `<form>` tag inside the `<div class="container">` tag, the outline only goes around the form.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="index.jsp">
            Username: ...
```

You might want to add some padding to make it look nice, too ;)

Also, please don't have a stroke to be able to ask your question. The "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." warning is there for a reason.